# C# Saving panel image gives different results

Tags: c#

Below is my code for changing my panel information into a Bitmap.
The Bitmap is first generated by my panel information and then saved to as a image file.
I confirmed that the width, height, and bounds represent the right information given by my panel.
I am currently unsure of why my result bmp/jpeg file is different from the image on my panel.

//bitmap saving function

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);
        Debug.WriteLine("bounds: " + panel1.ClientRectangle);
        this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Flaw\Desktop\Test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

//drawing function

```
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphicsObj;

        graphicsObj = this.panel1.CreateGraphics();

        Pen myPen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 5);
        graphicsObj.Clear(Color.White);
        //graphicsObj.DrawLine(myPen, 50, 50, 100, 100);
        if (bCircle)
        {
            graphicsObj.DrawEllipse(myPen, x, y, 100, 100);
        }
        else if (bSquare)
        {
            graphicsObj.DrawRectangle(myPen, x, y, 100, 100);
        }
```

The result I get by saving the bitmap.

[image]

The image that is on my panel1 (cropped from my Window Form)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Bounds property is the relationship the panel has to the parent container, so this won't always work:

```
this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.Bounds);
```

Try this instead:

```
this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
```

Your bitmap size should also use the ClientSize properties, since the panel's Width and Height properties include any border sizes:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);
```

Per your update, CreateGraphics is a temporary canvas and won't be a part of the panel, so there was nothing to save.  Use the panel's paint event instead:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  using (Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5)) {
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    if (bCircle) {
      e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, x, y, 100, 100);
    } else if (bSquare) {
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, x, y, 100, 100);
    }
  }
}
```

To make an update, you just need to invalidate the control:

```
panel1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: I updated the code as:  
        
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.ClientSize.Width, panel1.ClientSize.Height);
            Debug.WriteLine("bounds: " + panel1.ClientRectangle);
            this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
            bmp.Save(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Flaw\Desktop\Test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

But now the result is a solid gray colour same as windows form colour.

Comment: @user3235731 I don't know what's in your panel.  You need to document that.

Comment: @user3235731 Your edits to your post aren't helping.  Are you drawing in the panel?  Are their controls in the panel?  How did that panel get that black border?

Comment: That's kinda guessable.  Tell him to minimize and restore the window first :)

Comment: @HansPassant CreateGraphics, the usual suspect.

Comment: Sorry I think it is the CreateGraphics problem. The reason is that CreateGraphics is temporary or something right?

Comment: @user3235731 Absolutely, which is why I was looking for you to document your panel.  You have to use the panel's paint event, and use the graphics  object from the `e` parameter.

Comment: @user3235731 I updated the post now that you've shown your drawing code.